# Quadratic or cubic 1d interpolate without large interpolator-building overhead?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scipy

I'd like to quad or cube interpolate a long series of floats (or vectors) in 1d, where long could be 1E+05 or 1E+06 (or more). For some reason SciPi's handy `interp1d()`'s time overhead to prepare the interpolators scales as almost n^3 for both quadratic and cubic splines.

I don't need a spline interpolator necessarily. I can write one fairly easily (at least for equal-spaced data) that just uses the closest 3 or 4 points to do a local (piecewise) quadratic or cubic interpolation, though it may end up being ugly and possibly slow.

But I'm wondering if something like that exists already? Something *faster to generate* than the splines from `interp1d`?

Using scipy v.0.17.0 and numpy v.1.13.0

[image: time for interpolator]

Using a (what I thought was) recent Anaconda installation: scipy v.0.17.0 and numpy v.1.11.0

[image: time for interpolator]

```
import time
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

times = []
for n in np.logspace(1, 3.5, 6).astype(int):
    x = np.arange(n, dtype=float)
    y = np.vstack((np.cos(x), np.sin(x)))
    start = time.clock()
    bob = interp1d(x, y, kind='quadratic', assume_sorted=True)
    times.append((n, time.clock() - start))

n, tim = zip(*times)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(n, tim)
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.show()
```

Comment: On my mediocre laptop, the [output of your script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eI0ZC.png) looks very different. Not seeing this spline creation cost.

Comment: @FTP I forgot to specify `python 2.7` (my bad). I wonder if your iterators haven't iterated yet?

Comment: I don't see how, but to make sure there's no cheating going on, I inserted `print(bob(0.5))` - so bob is evidently evaluated. Same result.

Comment: @FTP okay well perhaps they are "just in time" iterated, so you'd have to do z = bob(x+0.1) which would generate *all possible parts* of the spline (or splines). I'm assuming that you are using newer versions of numpy and scipy than I have now?

Comment: Yes, I am using the newest Anaconda setup. I also tested on colab.research.google.com with similar results to my local setup.

Comment: @FTP okay thank you very much for your time and information, I'll keep on this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For some reason SciPi's handy interp1d()'s time overhead to prepare the interpolators scales as almost n^3 for both quadratic and cubic splines.

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49428804/3904031):

> Short answer: update your scipy installation.
>
> Longer answer: pre-0.19, interp1d was based on splmake which is using linear algebra with full matrices. In scipy 0.19, it was refactored to use banded linear algebra. As a result, (below is with scipy 0.19.1)

So the answer to *your question*:

> Quadratic or cubic 1d interpolate without large interpolator-building overhead?

is still use `scipy.interp1d` just not the old version of scipy that you were (in this case I was) using. Be sure to use scipy 0.19 or newer. Fyi version 1.0 has been released and so you (I) should update accordingly.