# Why would SciPy's interp1d take over a minute to build an interpolator?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I'd like to quad or cube interpolate a long series of floats (or vectors) in 1d, where long could be 1E+05 or 1E+06 (or more). For some reason SciPi's handy `interp1d()`'s time overhead to prepare the interpolators scales as almost n^3 for both quadratic and cubic splines, taking over a minute for a few thousand points.

According to comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49151547/3904031) (a question I will delete, I'm keeping it there temporarily for comment access) it takes a milli-second on other computers, so something is obviously pathologically wrong here.

My installation is a bit old, but SciPy's `.interp1d()` has been around for quite a while.

```
np.__version__    '1.13.0'
scipy.__version__ '0.17.0'
```

What can I do to try to figure out this incredible slowness for interpolation?

[image: time for interpolator]

```
import time
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

times = []
for n in np.logspace(1, 3.5, 6).astype(int):
    x = np.arange(n, dtype=float)
    y = np.vstack((np.cos(x), np.sin(x)))
    start = time.clock()
    bob = interp1d(x, y, kind='quadratic', assume_sorted=True)
    times.append((n, time.clock() - start))

n, tim = zip(*times)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(n, tim)
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Try with newer scipy , => 0.19 should be faster.

Comment: Yep, the [release notes](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/releases/tag/v0.19.0) for 0.19 say *`scipy.interpolate` improvements*.

Comment: @kazemakase Thanks. I will look into updating scipy when I can, but really the speed I am seeing is so unreasonable that it could not possibly be right even before an "improvement. Had I chosen 100,000 points it would taken *days* or *weeks*. It really seems like there must be something else wrong. But I will try the update as soon as I'm able.

Comment: @kazemakase you are right! See [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49428804/3904031) and this https://i.stack.imgur.com/FI5Ho.png It was refactored completely at 0.19 "improvement" was an understatement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: update your scipy installation.

Longer answer: pre-0.19, `interp1d` was based on `splmake` which is using linear algebra with full matrices. In scipy 0.19, it was refactored to use banded linear algebra. As a result, (below is with scipy 0.19.1)

```
In [14]: rndm = np.random.RandomState(1234) 

In [15]: for n in [100, 1000, 10000, int(1e6)]:
    ...:     x = np.sort(rndm.uniform(size=n))
    ...:     y = np.sin(x)
    ...:     %timeit interp1d(x, y, kind='quadratic', assume_sorted=True)
    ...:     
    ...:     

244 µs ± 4.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
422 µs ± 4.21 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
2.17 ms ± 50.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
227 ms ± 4.45 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [16]: 

In [16]: for n in [100, 1000, 10000, int(1e6)]:
    ...:     x = np.sort(rndm.uniform(size=n))
    ...:     y = np.sin(x)
    ...:     %timeit interp1d(x, y, kind='cubic', assume_sorted=True)
    ...:     
    ...:     

241 µs ± 4.67 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
462 µs ± 4.92 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
2.64 ms ± 37.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
276 ms ± 1.91 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Your other options are `CubicSpline` if you want cubic splines specifically (this is new in scipy 0.18) or `make_interp_spline` if you want also quadratic splines (new in scipy 0.19; this is what `interp1d` is using under the hood).

Comment: I see! So "improvement" is an understatement. Very nice, I'm sold, thanks!

Comment: @uhoh That's the curve I see too on version 19.1.

Comment: @kazemakase that's good to hear, thanks for the confirmation.